# trigonmetric integral (might be related to complex variable or Fourier series)

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $p\in \mathbb{N}.$ I would like to know how to compute
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^j(t) \cos(kt) dt, \quad \quad j,k\in \{1,2,\ldots,p\}.$$ Could somebody help me with this? It might be related to complex analysis (computing residue) or Fourier analysis. Thank you so much.

Mana

Answer (score 1):

Use
\begin{align}
\cos^j(t)&=\frac{(e^{it}+e^{-it})^j}{2^j}
\\&=\frac1{2^{j-1}}(\cos(jt)+\tbinom{j}{1}\cos((j-2)t)+\tbinom{j}{2}\cos((j-4)t)+…)
\end{align}
where the last term is $\frac12·\binom{j}{j/2}$ for even $j$ and $\binom{j}{(j-1)/2}\cos t$ for odd $j$.

Then apply what you know about the formula for the Fourier coefficients.